# Method of Characteristics - Initial Value Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find a formula for the characteristic ode with a initial condition $x(0) = x_0 > 0$.

$u_t+(1/x)u_x=0$

on $x > 0$ and $u(x,0) = f(x)$.

I understand the characteristic portion, but how do I incorporate the $x(0)$?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that you understand the characteristic portion, you found the general solution :
$$u(x,t)=F(x^2-2t)$$
where $F(X)$ is any differentiable function.

So, your problem is to determine which function $F(X)$ satisfies the condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is a given function.

The condition implies :
$$u(x,0)=F(x^2)=f(x)$$
With $X=x^2 \quad\to\quad x=\sqrt{X}$ , taking account of $x(0)>0$
$$F(X)=f(\sqrt{X})$$
So, $F(X)$ is determined. Coming back to the case $t\neq 0$ where $ X=x^2-2t$
$$u(x,t)=f(\sqrt{x^2-2t})$$